# Error: Option clash for package xcolor/babel (beamer de latex)

Tags: latex

Estoy intentando crear una presentación en beamer pero me da un error con los paquetes que no consigo solucionar, he añadido table a "documentclass" como encontré en internet pero no se me soluciona el problema:

```
\documentclass[11pt,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,warsaw,spanish,table,
latin,table]{beamer}
%
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.markings}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=south west, yshift=-2pt, xshift=1pt] at (current page.south west)
        {};
        \draw[PineGreen!35,line width=0.5mm] ([yshift=-1cm, xshift=0.25cm]current page.north west)
        -- ([yshift=-1cm, xshift=\paperwidth - 0.25cm]current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[spanish,table]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin,table]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding} %paquete para simbolo de manita
\usepackage{marvosym} %paquete para balon
\usepackage{bclogo} %paquete para simbolo de peligro
\usepackage{dingbat}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  COLORES

\definecolor{Verde}{cmyk}{1,0,1,0}
\definecolor{awesome}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67}
\definecolor{bb}{rgb}{0.11, 0.22, 0.73}
\definecolor{uclagold}{rgb}{1.0, 0.7, 0.0}
\definecolor{cadmiumorange}{rgb}{0.93, 0.53, 0.18}
\definecolor{carrotorange}{rgb}{0.93, 0.57, 0.13}
\definecolor{coral}{rgb}{1.0, 0.5, 0.31}
\definecolor{fawn}{rgb}{0.9, 0.67, 0.44}
\definecolor{calpolypomonagreen}{rgb}{0.12, 0.3, 0.17}
\definecolor{verdechillon}{rgb}{0.5, 1.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}
\definecolor{darkspringgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{barsa}{rgb}{.168,.19,.62}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COMANDOS
\spanishdecimal{.} %para que salga el punto decimal
\newcommand{\dm}{\HandRight}
%\newcommand{\ff}{\Football}
%\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=20cm]{pepe}} %para poner un fondo

\title[]{{ {{{La distribución Bivariante de Poisson}}}}}
\author[Fdez.-Ponce]{\textcolor{cobalt}{José María Fernández Ponce}}
\institute{\textcolor{cobalt}{Departamento de Estadística e Investigaci\'on Operativa   } \\ \textcolor{cobalt}{Universidad de Sevilla} \\ %\textcolor{cobalt}{(Entrenador de Fútbol, Nivel I)}}
%\date{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{datos2.jpg}}
%\hspace*{cm}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{balon.jpg}\hspace*{0.5cm}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{balon2.jpg}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm]{MarcaUs}}


\begin{document}
\author{María José Silva Reyes}
\date{2021}
\title{La distribución Bivariante de Poisson}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Contenido}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

El error que obtengo es :
Error: Option clash for package xcolor y Error: Option clash for package babel.
Estos errores los tengo con los paquetes "graphicx" y "bbding", aunque si comento estas líneas me aparecen en otro sitio.
Me gustaría saber como solucionar el problema, ¿alguna solución?
Gracias.